# Practicing Mongolian pronunciation before visiting Mongolia

Tags: mongolian-language

I'm planning on learning how to read Cyrillic, being able to speak Mongolian, and maybe being able to hear spoken Mongolian before visiting Mongolia.

There's a reasonable amount of Mongolian-language material on YouTube, and possibly material teaching Mongolian. But in order to learn pronunciation, I assume I'll need someone familiar with Mongolian to listen to me speaking and tell me when I'm getting it wrong, because I won't be able to hear certain variations in sound.

How can someone living in Sydney practice pronunciation?

Resources I've tried so far:

1. Gumtree: Nothing relevant in "Jobs" or "Language Swap".
2. Meetup: Nothing.
3. Googling for Mongolian lessons in Sydney: Nothing.

Comment: Mongolian isn't tonal so pronunciation isn't as critical as for Chinese. It does have a couple of slightly hard sounds or at least unusual ones. You should do fine from Youtube and I used a course on Memrise for audio vocab flashcards. Cyrillic is dead easy, just watch out for a couple of letters changing shape in italics. I'd rate Mongolian pronunciation as easier than Chinese, probably comparable to Korean in difficulty for an English speaker.

Comment: Have you tried to find Mongolian individuals, who settled down in the area? I would not know how to find then unless there is a restaurant, but a small add in a local newspaper might help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about language lessons at home, not travelling.

Comment: Grey area here.  It's sort of fringe related.

Comment: @Karlson yeah, but if you asked 'where in Sydney can I learn to swim before visiting Iceland' - it's not about the travel, it's about swimming lessons, that just happen to be before a holiday.  Where can I get a job before my holiday? Where can I buy a Sydney bus ticket before my holiday etc. I can see why it was asked here, but I think we need to be careful about these edge cases.

Comment: @MarkMayo It's sort of difficult to use Mongolian in Sydney.  Swimming not so much.

Comment: Indeed, but at some point there's a boundary. It's a case of working out where that is :/